# Perform function on subset of data

Tags: r, function, subset

I have a set of data below which shows a number of cars at an imaginary car dealership. The 'current_price' variable is obviously the price the car is currently set to sell at. The 'minimum_price' variable shows the hard floor price that the car must not, under any circumstance, sell at. (This can be assumed to be the purchase price).

I'm trying to create a function where the user can select a subset of the cars in the database (using the 'user defined parameters' as noted below), and then reduce or increase the 'Current_Price' by either a percentage or pound(£) value.

The 'minimum profit parameters' set the minimum profit which is to be made on all cars. In this example they have been set to £10 and 10%. Meaning the profit for each car must be either £10, or 10% of the current price - whichever is larger.

The price change parameters set how much the price is to move and whether it should move up or down.

```
# Dummy data
Type <- rep(c("Car", "Van"),each=3)
Age <- as.numeric(c(2, 2, 5, 4, 8,1))
Colour <- c("Red", "Red", "Yellow", "Red", "Black", "Red")
Make <- c("Ford", "VW", "VW", "VW", "BMW", "Ford")
Current_Price <- as.numeric(c(1050, 1000, 1500, 995, 2200, 2100))
Minimum_Price <- as.numeric(c(900, 600, 500, 850, 1900, 1950))
df1 <- data.frame(Type, Age, Colour, Make, Current_Price, Minimum_Price)

# User defined parameters - price to be changed for all cars which fit below selection
Input_Type <- "Car"
Input_Min_Age <- 2 # All cars this age and above
Input_Max_Age <- 10 # All cars this age and below
Input_Colour <- "Red"
Input_Make <- c("Ford", "VW")

# Minimum profit parameters
Input_Min_Pounds <- 10
Input_Min_Percentage <- 0.10

# Price change parameters
Input_Change_Type <- "Percentage" # "Percentage" or "Pound"
Input_Change_Value <- -0.10 # "-" sign to represent price reduction
```

Given the above, I would expect lines 1 & 2 to be effected by the change. Line 1's price should move down from £1,050 to £1,000. This is because £1,000 is the lowest price possible where 10% of the price is profit (900/(1-0.10) = 1000).

Line 2's price should simply move down by 10% to 900.

Has anyone got an idea how to put this into a function which will be fairly intuitive to use for someone who is not used to using R?

Comment: Just to be sure on your requirements: Does *"using the 'user defined parameters' as noted below"* mean the query parameters are always the same and only the parameter values are different? Or do you expect a fully flexible "query engine"?

Comment: Hi @RYoda. If you have a solution which allows only 1 of the parameters to be input then that would be ideal. (So if the 'colour' parameter is not defined then it is assumed all colours are to be affected by the change).

Comment: How would you define "intuitive to use" (for inexperienced R users)? Can I assume that the user knows the names of the data columns (so that the function could use the `...` argument)? Or can I assume a good intellisense support like that of RStudio so that the user can see the allowed arguments?

Comment: is it OK to use a `data.table` (which works faster and has leaner code) or do you stick to a `data.frame` solution?

Comment: BTW (IMHO): Please don't combine multiple questions/problems into one single SO question to keep the minimal reproducible example and the answers as simple as possible. Your questions combines three independent problems: 1. Pricing logic, 2. filtering logic, 3. usability (for non-R-users).

Comment: Hi @RYoda, thanks for your help so far. I've noted your suggestion on not combining questions into one post and must say I agree. This is to be used by people who are more than capable with Excel but have never used a programming language. I will show them anything that they need to know syntax-wise but I want to keep the code as clearly typed and easy to understand as possible.

Comment: Happy to use data.table if you think that would be a better solution. I've implemented what you've already written and I imagine now it's just a case of updating the price for the selected vehicles and doing a merge perhaps? I can insert some unique reference numbers to aid with this.

Comment: Merge? Do you want to update the price only in the result (sub set) or in the original "database" (`df1`)? Using a `data.table` makes it much easier to update the orginal "database" since it uses "by reference" instead of "copy on write" semantics.... Honestly I do also not understand your pricing logic: Where does the 10 percent profit margin come from? Is it a fixed value...?

Comment: I think it would be best to hold 2 databases by the end of the exercise, one showing the original price set, and one showing the same data but with the updated prices. Only the sub set of prices would need to have the price change affected on them. The pricing logic works like this: The "profit" (Current_Price - Minimum_Price) must not go below either of the user input 'minimum profit paramaters'. So for the example above, the profit must satisfy both:
Current_Price - Minimum_Price >= Input_Min_Pounds
Current_Price - Minimum_Price >= Current_Price/(1-Input_Min_Percentage)

Comment: So assuming the above minimum profit parameters of £10 or 10%, for a car with, say, Current_Price == 1050 & Minimum_Price == 900, the Current_Price must be >= 910 (Minimum_Price + Input_Min_Pounds) and >= 1000 (Minimum_Price/(1-Input_Min_Percentage)).

If the Input_Change_Type were set to "Percentage" and the Input_Change_Value were set to, say, -0.50 (indicating a 50% reduction in price). The full 50% discount would not be actioned. Instead the price would be reduced as far as possible without falling out of the limits mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer uses a `data.table`** to support the price changes in the original "data.frame" (as you have explained in the comments to your question) the solution could look like this.

I am still ignoring the pricing logic because I want to focus on the usability aspect
(this specialized pricing logic is arbitrary and not of particular interest for anybody else here at SO; if you have a specific problem to implement it yourself please open a new question and explain the problem in detail).

```
library(data.table)

data <- as.data.table(df1)

calc_price <- function(Current_Price,
                       Minimum_Price,
                       price_change_type,
                       price_change_value,
                       min_profit_pounds,
                       min_profit_percentage) {
  # TODO implement your pricing logic here...
  return(Current_Price + 1)
}

update_car_prices <- function(data,
                              filter,
                              price_change_type     = c("Percentage", "Pound"),
                              price_change_value    = 0,
                              min_profit_pounds     = 10,
                              min_profit_percentage = 0.10) {

  stopifnot(is.data.table(data))

  price_change_type <- match.arg(price_change_type)  # use the first value if none was provided
  filter_exp        <- substitute(filter)            # "parse" the passed value as expression
  # date the price using a separate function to encapsulate the logic
  data[eval(filter_exp), Current_Price := calc_price(Current_Price,
                                                     Minimum_Price,
                                                     price_change_type,
                                                     price_change_value,
                                                     min_profit_pounds,
                                                     min_profit_percentage)][]
  return(data)
}
```

The usage is still similar to my `data.frame` answer, e. g.:

```
update_car_prices(data, Type == "Car" & Age >= 2 & Age <= 10 & Colour == "Red" & Make %in% c("Ford", "VW"))
update_car_prices(data, Colour == "Red")
update_car_prices(data, Colour == "Red", "Pound", 500)
```

The differences are:

1. The whole `data.table` (`data`) is returned to see the impact
2. The original `data` is changed since `data.table`s are passed by reference
   and I am updating the price "by reference" using the data.table syntax `:=`

Comment: Welcome :-) PS: I guess a combination of `if` (or `ifelse`) plus `pmax` suffice to implement your pricing logic...

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is based on a `data.frame`...**

Your questions addresses multiple aspects (pricing logic, filtering logic and usability).

I am focusing on the usability (and ignoring the pricing logic since this is just a deliberate detail).

I see at least three options:

1. Use a strongly typed function:

   `get_car_prices1 <- function(data, Input_Type, Input_Min_Age, Input_Max_Age, Input_Colour, Input_Make, Input_Min_Pounds, Input_Min_Percentage)`
2. Use an "untyped" function with a deliberate number of arguments via `...` to support filtering by passing only the required arguments:

   `get_car_prices2 <- function(data, Input_Min_Pounds, Input_Min_Percentage, ...)`
3. Use meta programming with `substitute` + `eval`

I have decided for option 3 as being the best (user friendly + flexible) option IMHO:

```
get_car_prices <- function(data,
                           filter,
                           price_change_type  = c("Percentage", "Pound"),
                           price_change_value = 1)
{
  price_change_type <- match.arg(price_change_type)  # use the first value if none was provided
  filter_exp        <- substitute(filter)            # "parse" the passed value as expression
  data_subset       <- subset(data, eval(filter_exp))
  # TODO add your pricing logic here (e. g. using "ifelse")
  return(data_subset)
}

# Usage examples:

get_car_prices(df1, Colour == "Red")
#   Type Age Colour Make Current_Price Minimum_Price
# 1  Car   2    Red Ford          1050           900
# 2  Car   2    Red   VW          1000           600
# 4  Van   4    Red   VW           995           850
# 6  Van   1    Red Ford          2100          1950

get_car_prices(df1, Type == "Car" & Age >= 2 & Age <= 10 & Colour == "Red" & Make %in% c("Ford", "VW"))
#   Type Age Colour Make Current_Price Minimum_Price
# 1  Car   2    Red Ford          1050           900
# 2  Car   2    Red   VW          1000           600

get_car_prices(df1, Colour == "Red", "Pound", 500)
# ...

get_car_prices(df1, Colour == "Red", "dumping price", 1)
# Error in match.arg(price_change_type) : 
#   'arg' should be one of “Percentage”, “Pound” 

# But: The user has to learn at least the expression logic of R and that variables (and values) are case-sensitive:
get_car_prices(df1, Colour == "red")
# [1] Type          Age           Colour        Make          Current_Price Minimum_Price
#  <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

# Error: Assignment operator (=) used instead of comparison operator (==)
get_car_prices(df1, Colour = "Red")
# Error in get_car_prices(df1, Colour = "Red") : 
#   unused argument (Colour = "Red")
```